# How connect by level is working with two diff lengths?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to understand below query

```
select
name,
country,
completePath,
regex_substr(completePath, '[^|]+', 1, lvl) parentOf
from Table
CROSS JOIN lateral
(
select LEVEL lvl from dual connect by LEVEL <= length(completePath) - length(replace(completePath, '|')) + 1)
```

completePath value is like `|ABC|EFG|HIG|JKL|LMN`

getting hard time to understand this.

Can anyone please help me to understand with any small example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `length(completePath)` counts the number of characters in `completePath`
- `length(replace(completePath, '|'))` counts the number of characters in `completePath` after removing the `|` characters.
- Therefore, `length(completePath) - length(replace(completePath, '|'))` gives the count of the number of `|` characters.

All it is doing is giving you a count of the number of `|` delimiter characters that are separating terms in your delimited string and then by adding `1` you would get the maximum number of terms in that delimited string.

For example, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (completePath) AS
  SELECT 'AB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A|B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A|B|C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC|DEF|GHI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '|ABC|DEF|G|HI' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT completePath,
       length(completePath) AS num_chars,
       length(replace(completePath, '|')) AS num_chars_no_pipe,
       length(completePath) - length(replace(completePath, '|')) + 1 AS max_num_terms,
       REGEXP_COUNT(completePath, '[^|]+') AS actual_num_terms
FROM   Table_Name
```

Outputs:

| COMPLETEPATH | NUM_CHARS | NUM_CHARS_NO_PIPE | MAX_NUM_TERMS | ACTUAL_NUM_TERMS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| A|B | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| A|B|C | 5 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| ABC|DEF|GHI | 11 | 9 | 3 | 3 |
| |ABC|DEF|G|HI | 13 | 9 | 5 | 4 |

With the last example, there could be an empty-string term before the first character so the maximum number of terms is 5 even though there are only actually 4 non-empty terms. Your regular expression will not match that empty first term as it is only looking for matches of length 1-or-more; to match empty terms you would want the regular expression `[^|]*(\||$)`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MguE261n)

Comment: in this |ABC|EFG|HIG|JKL|LMN, I'll get 5 as counts for pipe(|), but what's a point of adding 1 in it to make it 6 ?

Comment: @OxanaGrey There could be an empty-string term before the first pipe giving a 6th term. However, your regular expression would not match an empty string.

Comment: and how join is working here ?... not able to understand how its working with join condition ? I'm not able to relate LEVEL joined with the condition mentioned in query, Is there any way I could see how all LEVEL values looks like before its going for joining condition...not able picturize the process...Can you please suggest ?

Comment: @OxanaGrey The join is a `CROSS JOIN` (the `LATERAL` keyword was introduced in Oracle 12 and just means that a column from the left table is being used in the query to generate the right table). The table on the left of the `CROSS JOIN` has a delimited string and the query on the right of the join will generate `n` rows, for each row in the left table, with the values `1` through `n` where `n` is the (maximum) number of terms in the delimited string in the left table. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BFmnyMv7)